# Sync database on server with database local machine

Tags: postgresql

I have a database on my server which I could like to have on my laptop so I can use it for development. Is there a way to do this? I was using the default SQLite database with Django but now I'm using PostgreSQL which isn't part of the repo.

Comment: Postgres is Open Source. Go to https://www.postgresql.org/download/ and download the version for your system.

Comment: That's not even close to what I'm asking.. Basically I want to backup the production database and use it in development

Comment: Then perhaps you could re-phrase the question to ask about export (from SQLite) -import (to Postgres) data instead of the change of database from SQLite to Postgres.